# Sed/awk/perl: reversing order of comma separated values, preserving other text

Tags: sed, awk, perl, sort

I have this text:

```
LABEL1
    .BYTE 01, 02, 03, 04, 05
    .BYTE 01, 02, 03
```

I need to reverse only comma separated values order:

```
LABEL1
    .BYTE 05, 04, 03, 02, 01
    .BYTE 03, 02, 01
```

I need this working with things like:

```
ITINERARY_ARRAY_01
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_00A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_01A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_02A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_03A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_04A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_05A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_06A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_07A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_08A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_09A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_10A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_11A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_12A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_13A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_14A
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01E
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01F
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01G
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01H
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $13, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01I
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $11, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01J
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $20, $1E, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01K
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $13, $15, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01L
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $20, $1E, $1C, $27
    .BYTE $00
;---------------------
```

where nothing needs to be changed, except values after ".BYTE", that must be in reverse order, hexadecimal format, using "$" as prefix...
Sorry for this "edit" but i see this only now.
Thanks again !

Comment: Please add more clarification. What have you tried so far? How can you tell the difference between what needs to remain in place (`.BYTE`) and what needs to be reversed (the rest of the line)? Can we assume the comma-separated values consist only of digits? Can they have a fractional part? Can they be negative?

Comment: I write here but want to include a reply also to cuonglm.
cuonglm script is functionally and useful, but now i see that i need a more complex thing.
I edited my post as well.
Tanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File `revbytes2.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=",? +"
}
NF>2 && match($0,"^ +\.BYTE ") {
        printf substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
        for(i=NF;i>3;i--) printf $i", "
        print $3
        next
}
1
```

`FS=",? +"` makes `awk` recognise the space after `.BYTE` and the `,` plus space sequence between the bytes as field separator.

For each line this will look for lines with more than 2 fields starting with spaces followed by `.BYTE` and one space and rember the start and length of this prefix in `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` as side effect of the `match(...)` expression.

If this match is found and there are more than 2 fields, the prefix is cut from the original line using `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` and printed followed by the remaining fields in reverse order.

If the spaces plus `.BYTE` plus space prefix was not found or there were not more than 2 fields, the line will be printed as is. So this will be done for a `.BYTE`-line defining only one byte too, because there is nothing to reverse.

Test run:

```
$ diff -u$(wc -l <input) input <(awk -f revbytes2.awk input)
--- input       2014-10-19 06:04:48.280714146 +0200
+++ /dev/fd/63  2014-10-19 22:40:01.385538235 +0200
@@ -1,42 +1,42 @@
 ITINERARY_ARRAY_01
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_00A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_01A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_02A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_03A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_04A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_05A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_06A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_07A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_08A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_09A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_10A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_11A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_12A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_13A
     .BYTE <ITINERARY_14A
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01E
-    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $07, $05, $03
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01F
-    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $09, $07, $05, $03
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01G
-    .BYTE $28, $0D, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $0D, $28
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01H
-    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $13, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $13, $0F, $0D, $28
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01I
-    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $11, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $11, $0F, $0D, $28
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01J
-    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $20, $1E, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $1E, $20, $09, $07, $05, $03
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01K
-    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $13, $15, $00
+    .BYTE $00, $15, $13, $0F, $0D, $28
 ;-------------------
 ITINERARY_01L
-    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $20, $1E, $1C, $27
+    .BYTE $27, $1C, $1E, $20, $09, $07, $05, $03
     .BYTE $00
 ;---------------------
```

Comparing `mawk` and `gawk` output:

```
$ diff <(mawk -f revbytes2.awk input) <(gawk -f revbytes2.awk input)
gawk: revbytes2.awk:5: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
```

Obvioisly no differences on stdout. Good!

The warning vanishes if you write `"^ +\056BYTE "` instead of `"^ +\.BYTE "` inside the `match(...)` expression.

Maybe someone using `gawk` frequently knows a better way to avoid the warning.

Comment: I have an "undefined I funtion" on this line "for(i=NF;i>2;i--)". awk -V
GNU Awk 4.0.1

Comment: `gawk3` complains too. Sorry... I'm using `mawk` as my default `awk` and need to think about `mawk` vs `gawk` differences for a while.

Comment: @FlavioPasqualin: Please retry.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but i solved the "escape sequence" error using "\\." Seems to work. Later i will try if script works...

Comment: Ok. Last version works !

Comment: @FlavioPasqualin ... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here I do it with `sed`:

```
sed '/,/!b                                                   
s/\( *[^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\2,\n\1/;:t
s/\([^,]*,\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/;tt
s/\n\(.*\),/\1/' <<\DATA
LABEL1
    .BYTE 01, 02, 03, 04, 05
    .BYTE 01, 02, 03        
LABEL1
    .BYTE 01, 02, 03, 04, 05
    .BYTE 01, 02, 03
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
LABEL1
    .BYTE 05, 04, 03, 02, 01 
    .BYTE 03, 02, 01 
LABEL1
    .BYTE 05, 04, 03, 02, 01 
    .BYTE 03, 02, 01
```

It checks for a comma on the current line. If there is `!`no comma, `sed` `b`ranches out of the script and autoprints the line. If the line *does* contain a comma `sed` does the following:

1. It first prepares the line by `s///`ubstituting the following:

   - `\( *[^ ]*\)` - the first occurring sequence of zero or more spaces followed immediately by a sequence of zero or more not space characters referenced as `\1` followed immediately by...
   - `\(.*\)` - everything else on the line referenced as `\2`...
   - ...with `\2,\n\1`
   - *Note* - using the `\n` escape in the right-hand `s///`ubstitution field like this is not fully portable. For a `sed` that does not support it, it can be done instead by substituting a literal newline for the `n` in the statement.
2. It `:`defines a branch/test label called `t`.
3. While it still can, `sed` `s///`ubstitutes:

   - `\([^,]*,\)` - A sequence of zero or more not comma characters *then* a single comma referenced as `\1` followed immediately by...
   - `\(\n.*\)` - A sequence beginning with at least one `\n`ewline character followed by anything/everything remaining in pattern space referenced as `\2`...
   - ...with `\2\1`.
4. If the previous `s///`ubstitution `t`ests successful, `sed` branches back to the `:t`est label and tries again.
5. Last `sed` does a little cleanup and replaces:

   - `\n\(.*\),` - the first occurring `\n`ewline character and the last occurring comma...
   - `\1` - ...with all that lies between.

As `sed` does the recursive replacement, the `\n`ewline delimiter walks backwards one comma-delimited field at a time. It stops the replacements when the `\n`ewline is the first character on the line. Here's a `l`ook at its progress through the recursive replacement process:

```
 01, 02, 03, 04, 05,\n    .BYTE$
 01, 02, 03, 04,\n    .BYTE 05,$
 01, 02, 03,\n    .BYTE 05, 04,$
 01, 02,\n    .BYTE 05, 04, 03,$
 01,\n    .BYTE 05, 04, 03, 02,$
\n    .BYTE 05, 04, 03, 02, 01,$
```

After its initial preparatory substitution, `sed` does not delimit on anything but commas and the inserted `\n`ewline character. So *any* kind of comma-separated values work fine. Here's the output from running your long bit through it:

```
ITINERARY_ARRAY_01
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_00A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_01A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_02A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_03A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_04A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_05A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_06A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_07A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_08A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_09A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_10A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_11A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_12A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_13A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_14A
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01E
    .BYTE $00, $07, $05, $03 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01F
    .BYTE $00, $09, $07, $05, $03 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01G
    .BYTE $00, $0D, $28 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01H
    .BYTE $00, $13, $0F, $0D, $28 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01I
    .BYTE $00, $11, $0F, $0D, $28 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01J
    .BYTE $00, $1E, $20, $09, $07, $05, $03 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01K
    .BYTE $00, $15, $13, $0F, $0D, $28 
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01L
    .BYTE $27, $1C, $1E, $20, $09, $07, $05, $03
    .BYTE $00
;---------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
perl -MTie::File -e'
    tie @lines,"Tie::File","your_file";
    for(@lines){
        next unless /,/; # Skip lines with no commas
        $csv = /(\s*[^,\s]+,.*)/;
        $new_csv = join ",",reverse split /,/,$csv;
        s/\Q$csv/$new_csv/;
    }'
```

**Disclaimer!!**

This will modify your file *in situ*. Use a dummy copy of the file if that's not desired.

**A version that will not modify the original file**

```
perl -pe'
        next unless /,/; # Skip lines with no commas
        chomp;
        $csv = /(\s*[^,\s]+,.*)/;
        $new_csv = join ",",reverse split /,/,$csv;
        $new_csv .= "\n"; # The newline removed by chomp
        s/\Q$csv/$new_csv/;
    ' your_file
```

**Assumptions**

- You don't care about the spacing around the commas.
- The first of the CSV values is offset from `.BYTE` by at least a single space.
- By "reversing the order" you mean reverse the order they're found in in the file not sorting by descending numerical order.

**Input**

```
ITINERARY_ARRAY_01
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_00A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_01A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_02A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_03A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_04A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_05A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_06A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_07A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_08A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_09A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_10A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_11A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_12A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_13A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_14A
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01E
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01F
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01G
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01H
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $13, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01I
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $11, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01J
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $20, $1E, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01K
    .BYTE $28, $0D, $0F, $13, $15, $00
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01L
    .BYTE $03, $05, $07, $09, $20, $1E, $1C, $27
    .BYTE $00
;---------------------
```

**Output**

```
ITINERARY_ARRAY_01
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_00A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_01A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_02A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_03A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_04A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_05A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_06A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_07A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_08A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_09A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_10A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_11A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_12A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_13A
    .BYTE <ITINERARY_14A
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01E
    .BYTE $00, $07, $05, $03
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01F
    .BYTE $00, $09, $07, $05, $03
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01G
    .BYTE $00, $0D, $28
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01H
    .BYTE $00, $13, $0F, $0D, $28
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01I
    .BYTE $00, $11, $0F, $0D, $28
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01J
    .BYTE $00, $1E, $20, $09, $07, $05, $03
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01K
    .BYTE $00, $15, $13, $0F, $0D, $28
;-------------------
ITINERARY_01L
    .BYTE $27, $1C, $1E, $20, $09, $07, $05, $03
    .BYTE $00
;---------------------
```

Comment: with this i obtain things like:
ITINERARY_14H
    .BYTE $26, $24, $1
8, $16, $00;-------------------
ITINERARY_14I
    .BYTE $26, $24, $1
A, $1B, $1D, $21, $00;-------------------
ITINERARY_14J
    .BYTE $26, $24, $1
A, $1B, $00;-------------------
ITINERARY_14K
    .BYTE $26, $24, $1
8, $00;-------------------
ITINERARY_14L
    .BYTE $26, $24, $00;-------------------
ITINERARY_14M
    .BYTE $26, $00;-------------------

perl -version

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

With your second script, last "}" gives an error too.

Comment: @FlavioPasqualin You're right, the `}` in the second version was extraneous. I removed it. But since the formatting in the comments is terrible, can you please clarify what the problem you're getting is?

Comment: Yep... using comment is quite problematic to see... but i try to explain: where you see a space between numbers, like "$24, $1 8, $16" or "$26, $24, $1 A, $1B, $1D, $21, $00" i have the newline "\n", and there isn't at the end of line, so "$00;-------------------" etc, are on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

With your input, you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -MText::Tabs -anle '
    BEGIN {$tabstop = 4};
    print and next if /^\S/;
    @nums = grep { $_ =~ /\d+/ } @F;
    map { s/\D//g } @nums;
    map { $_ = (pop @nums) . (@nums==0 ? "" : ",")
        if $_ =~ /\d+/ } @F;
    print expand "\t@F";
' file
LABEL1
    .BYTE 05, 04, 03, 02, 01
    .BYTE 03, 02, 01
```

I assume that your original input was sorted. If not, you can use `@nums = sort { $a <=> $b } grep { $_ =~ /\d+/ } @F;` instead of `@nums = grep { $_ =~ /\d+/ } @F;`.